# Connecting spark clusters

Tags: apache-spark

Connecting spark clusters in this way: spark://master:7707 but instead of submitting tasks in the way of spark-submit instead of running the main method directly, is this running on the spark cluster?

```
object SparkPi {    
  def main(args: Array[String]) {    
    val conf = new SparkConf()
                  .setAppName("Spark Pi")
                  .setMaster("spark://master:7707")

    val spark = new SparkContext(conf)    
    val slices = if (args.length > 0) args(0).toInt else 2    
    val n = 100000 * slices    
    val count = spark.parallelize(1 to n, slices).map { i =>    
      val x = random * 2 - 1    
      val y = random * 2 - 1    
      if (x*x + y*y < 1) 1 else 0    
    }.reduce(_ + _)    
    println("Pi is roughly " + 4.0 * count / n)    
    spark.stop()    
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you execute this application directly using the `java` command, the process created will be running the Spark **driver** in client mode.

For this to run on the cluster, you would have to use spark-submit.

Please note that it's just the driver that will be running on the machine executing this main method. The jobs will be running on the cluster of workers and computation will take place there (that's unless your master is set to `local`, which is not the case in your example code)

Comment: That is, even if I specify new SparkConf ().SetMaster ("spark://master:7707") in the code, but not in the form of spark-submit, then the program runs locally, not on a cluster, is it?

Comment: @eason Yes, driver runs locally, but jobs run on cluster. With a remote master address, it's like submitting in client mode.

Comment: thinks,i will try